# Mysql - Convert String Array into multiple rows of a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a string variable which is received as input to a stored procedure since MySQL doesn't support arrays.

```
arr='ra,ba,ca,da'
```

and I wanted to convert that into table of values

```
Table
-----
 ra
 ba
 ca
 da
```

What would be the simplest select statement to achieve that?

Comment: Is there a maximum number of items in the string? If not, you need to write a stored procedure to do it. If there is, you can use `UNION` of queries that use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to select each item up to the maximum.

Comment: @barmar I am looking for a simple SQL statement that can achieve this task, can you please share the query? I tried no. of options to do so but did not succeed.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you tried. If it's really true that none of the ideas in the linked question work, I'll reopen and we can try helping you.

Comment: Note that it won't be a "simple SQL statement". There's nothing built into SQL that does this, you have to write code. Is there a reason you have to do it in SQL rather than a client application language? Most programming languages have simple functions or library routines to split a comma-separated string.

Comment: @barmar The linked question that you added is reading out of a table and exploding out into a new table. In my case, the input is stored as a variable, and how to convert that into a table was a challenge. I wanted to do this since MySQL doesn't support anything like array data type, so the input to the stored procedure will be an array which is actually a string separated by a comma, and then I actually wanted to convert each value into a separate row in a table to perform the further action over it.

Comment: You use the same method whether you're getting the data from a variable or a table. Just replace `(SELECT column FROM table)` with `(SELECT @arr)`

Comment: If it's a stored procedure, you can use a loop in the procedure, you don't need to create a table.

Comment: Here's another helpful question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845737/mysql-split-a-string-and-insert-into-table